# Extract variable to const by default in Webstorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm

In WebStorm, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> allows to extract the selected text to a variable :

[image: extract to variable]

Most of the time, I need to extract the variable to a `const` but WebStorm extracts it to a `let` by default.

How can I change this behavior ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to change defaults ( see [WEB-26073](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26073)); but, once you select `const` type, it will be suggested by default on next refactoring invocation

Comment: As of 2022.1 it seems it takes trying a few extract variables to get this to show up, but finally did.

Comment: @lena, is there a way to select the `const` from that small menu using the keyboard?

Comment: you can use mnemonics - `Alt+c` for `const`, `Alt+l` for `let`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can choose in a popup window
Version: WebStorm 2021.3.3

[image]